# Can a feed wire also be used as a relay trigger?

Tags: relay, dimmer, trigger

Can I use a low voltage wire (10.5 V) as a supply AND trigger With a single pole double throw relay? Is there a solid state option available?

I need a way to switch power back and fourth to LED lights from one 12 V wire to a 10.5 V wire (dimming feature) but I would like the 10.5 V wire to activate the relay. Would I need diodes as well? The 10.5 V wire activates auto dimming for another component too.

I apologize for the crude schematic. lol

[image: drawing]

[image: drawing 2]

[image: pic 3]

Comment: Many systems use a relay which delivers the same power source that activates it to a load; for example battery backups that don't mind a brief gap when the power fed to and through the relay is lost.  Your question would benefit from more detail, typically one dims LEDs with PWM not a different voltage...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added another image for more info as requested.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq8NcS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible solution.*

When the 10.5 V turns on the relay will energise and switch the LEDs to the 10.5 V supply. Otherwise the 12 V supply will power the lamp.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the 10.5v supply it may be happier if the relay has a catch diode.  But if it's actually some LED driver output and not simply a supply, the relay may not like it.

Comment: The 10.5v output is from an ECU that activates the voltage to dim (clock). I hav added another image for clarity. Thanks for your reply.